# multiple form insert query mysql

Tags: php, mysql

is there anyone know how to format this array in a loop so that it will insert in a database in a single query but in a loop way using php.

I'm making a multiple form by the way.

here's the array format of the field and this is my form looks like [attendance](http://abe.net63.net/pis.jpg)

```html
Array
(
    [sup_payroll_type] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 1
        )

    [sup_month] => Array
        (
            [0] => January
            [1] => January
            [2] => May
        )

    [sup_year] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2015
            [1] => 2015
            [2] => 2015
        )

    [sup_late_days] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
        )

    [sup_absent_days] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 0
        )

    [sup_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 6
        )

    [sup_emp_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 24
            [1] => 24
            [2] => 24
        )

    [save_edit_satt] => Array
        (
            [0] => SAVE
        )

)
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You mean, above array's first value would be stored in database and continuously to second, third...... using a loop right!

Comment: U r using mysql or mysqli?

Comment: what i mean is, there should be 3 insert query in the above array. looks like this one:  - insert into attendance( $field[sup_payroll_type][0], $field[sup_month][0], $field[sup_year][0], $field[sup_late_days][0], . . . . ) values  ('1','January','2015','1', . . . . ) ...  inside the loop.. btw im using mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below loop:-

```
$insertQuery = 'INSERT INTO attendence (sup_payroll_type, sup_month, sup_year, 
                sup_late_days, sup_absent_days, sup_id, sup_emp_id, 
                save_edit_satt) VALUES';
foreach($attendenceArray AS $key => $value){
    $insertQuery .= '("'.$value['sup_payroll_type'].'","'.$value['sup_month'].'",
                    "'.$value['sup_year'].'","'.$value['sup_late_days'].'",
                    "'.$value['sup_absent_days'].'","'.$value['sup_id'].'",
                    "'.$value['sup_emp_id'].'","'.$value['save_edit_satt'].'"),';    
}
$insertQuery = rtrim($insertQuery,',');
```

$insertQuery contains ur insert query. 
 $attendenceArray contains ur example array.

If ur using mysqli then used mysqli_query($mysqli,$insertQuery) to execute ur query. $mysqli is connection object.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with using a loop only

```
 $insertQuery = 'INSERT INTO attendence (sup_payroll_type, sup_month, sup_year, 
            sup_late_days, sup_absent_days, sup_id, sup_emp_id, 
            save_edit_satt) VALUES';
 foreach($attendenceArray['sup_payroll_type'] AS $key => $value){
 $insertQuery .= '("'.$value.'","'.$attendenceArray['sup_month'][$key].'",
                "'.$attendenceArray['sup_year'][$key].'","'.$attendenceArray['sup_late_days'][$key].'",
                "'.$attendenceArray['sup_absent_days'][$key].'","'.$attendenceArray['sup_id'][$key].'",
                "'.$attendenceArray['sup_emp_id'][$key].'","'.$attendenceArray['save_edit_satt'][$key].'"),';    
}

echo $insertQuery; // Query for insert
```

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out.

```html
$ctr = 0;
foreach($_POST['sup_payroll_type'] as $row){

 $upd_value        = array();
 $upd_value['sup_payroll_type']   = $_POST['sup_payroll_type'][$ctr];
 $upd_value['sup_month']    = $_POST['sup_month'][$ctr];
 $upd_value['sup_year']     = $_POST['sup_year'][$ctr];
 $upd_value['sup_late_days']   = $_POST['sup_late_days'][$ctr];
 $upd_value['sup_absent_days']   = $_POST['sup_absent_days'][$ctr];
 $upd_value['sup_emp_id']    = $_POST['sup_emp_id'][$ctr];

 $upd_result = $db_conn->mysql_update($upd_value,'tbl_attendance_support','sup_id='.$_POST['sup_id'][$ctr],'db_norkis');

 $ctr++;
}
```

BTW thanks Pankaj K and Shijin for sharing your idea =)